# A few questions on Torus Knots

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, knot-theory

Are all torus knots rational knots (2 bridge knots?)

Also, does anyone know where I can find an explcit formula for the Jones / Alexnader / HOMFLY polynomial for Torus knots??? What about when they are of type (2,2k+1)?

I'd really appreciate it!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are torus knots which are not rational knots.  The only torus knots which are 2-bridge knots are of the form $T(2,n)$, which is of course, the same as $T(n,2)$.  These are the same as the rational knot associated to $\frac{1}{n}$.

Jones himself was the first to compute the Jones polynomial for torus knots.  Link [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Evfr/jonesakl.pdf).  Look at the very end of that pdf to see that for a $T(p,q)$ torus knot, the Jones polynomial is

$$ \frac{t^{ \frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{2}  }}{1-t^2} (1−t^{p+1}−t^{q+1}+t^{p+q})  $$

For the others, I am not sure if there are general formula, but [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TorusKnot.html) has a recurrence relation for the Bracket polynomial of torus knots $T(2,n)$, so you should be able to apply to your case in some way, but this is closer to the Jones polynomial than the other two.

But $T(2,2k+1)$ is a pretty nice class of knots, so I wouldn't be surprised if you dig around you can find more about this class of knots' polynomials.

Comment: Thank you so much sir!!!!!!