# Question on the colored Jones polynomial (from Wikipedia)

Tags: knot-theory

I'm trying to understand how "coloring" the component of a link changes the link. I'm looking at the picture for the section on the colored Jones polynomial on the link provided, and was wondering if somebody could tell me what the contents of the rectangle with the label [n cable]. Am i correct in assuming that the larger rectangle on the left just has n copies of the link L running parallel to each other? Thanks!!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jones_polynomial#Colored_Jones_polynomial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rectangle with contents "$N$ cable" does not represent a block of the link diagram.  It labels the number of duplicates of the knot in the cabling, in particular, there are $N$ copies of the knot in the cabling.

The poorly described diagram seems to be representing a knot as an unspecified braid, represented by the large empty rectangle on the left, that has been closed, represented by the four strands that meet the large rectangle along its top and bottom edges and pass around to the right of the diagram, that has an $N$-cabling, represented by the label that you ask about.  (For the description as a closed braid, compare/contrast Figure 4 at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.07910.pdf .)  For Jones polynomial calculations, representing the knot as a closed braid is a substantial (conceptual) aid to computation.

A cabling is a specific kind of [satellite knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_knot).  Start with a closed [regular neighborhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubular_neighborhood), $n(K)$, of the knot $K$.  (This neighborhood is homeomorphic to a solid torus, but rather than imagine a "doughnut", unless you really are thinking of the colored Jones polynomial of the unknot, the solid torus is knotted.)  On the surface of $n(K)$, draw a [torus knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus_knot).  This torus knot is a cabling of $K$.

For the purpose of the colored Jones polynomial, it matters how many longitudinal copies of the knot are cut by a meridional disk of the solid torus (minimized under isotopy), but it doesn't really matter how they revolve around the core of the solid torus as they proceed along the knot as long as each strand closes itself off.  That is, as long as the number of $2\pi/N$ revolutions is a multiple of $N$.  (In general, if there are $m$ of $2\pi/N$ revolutions, there are $\gcd(m,N)$ parallel closed curves on the surface, each of which is an $N/\gcd(m,N)$ cabling of the original knot.)

Comment: Do you know if there are any non-trivial colors and examples of two bridge knots such that when you apply the color to the knot, the resulting knot is still a two bridge knot??

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa : When you apply $N$ colors to a knot, you get a link with $N$ components, so not a knot.  Each component is still 2-bridge, but I make no claims about the whole link.

Comment: One more unrelated question if you don't mind. I am wondering when a torus knot is a two bridge knot. According to an answer i got here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3724051/a-few-questions-on-torus-knots/3726887#3726887

all torus knots of the form $(2,n)$ are 2-bridge knots, but another source told me that only torus knots of the form $(2,2n+1)$ are 2-bridge knots. Thanks man I really appreciate it!!

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa : Both claims are the same.  For $(p,q)$ to give a torus **knot**, $\gcd(p,q) = 1$ is required.  (Otherwise, as noted in the last paragraph of the Answer, you get a link of parallel torus knots.)  So for $(2,n)$ to be a torus **knot**, $n$ has to be odd.  To the bridge number of torus knots, Schubert shows that a $(p,q)$ torus knot (so, implicitly, $\gcd(p,q) = 1$) has bridge number $\min\{p,q\}$.  (A more recent [proof](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~jcs/pubs/tknots.pdf).)  Therefore, any 2-bridge torus knot is either $(2,n)$ or $(n,2)$ with $n$ odd.  (continued)

Comment: Cool, and so given a pair of integers $(2,n)$ with $n$ odd, if you follow the follow the construction to create a torus knot, you will get the same knot as if you follow the construction for the rational knot of $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa : (actually, nothing to add).

Comment: Maybe you mean "2/n"?  (In which case, I think so, but I never remember whether the components swap or don't going from the (p,q) to the $a/b$, so check your conventions to make sure you are conforming with them.)

Comment: Nah, I meant $\frac{1}{n}$, as in the link that I posted above. Do you know any references that I could read to understand the geometric construction of the colored Jones polynomial??? I'm trying to find a subclass of 2-bridge knots that when I color them by $N=2$, they are still a 2-bridge knot. 

Since the torus knot $(2,n)$ corresponds to the rational knot $K(\frac{1}{n})$ (as according to the link I posted), this is my top candidate so far.

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa : Oh, right, Conway's rational knots.  I don't konw much about Conway's rational knots, so I won't speculate.
Regarding construction of the colored Jones polynomial, the link in my answer ( https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.07910.pdf ) is one I have used to gain insight.  I can't say I know of a pictorial mechanism (because the "colors" are really [irreducible representations](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/irreducible+representation)).

Comment: So the idea is that you start with a knot, color it by $N=2$, and you will have a 2-component link. If we use the crappy wikipedia picture, the big empty box on the left will be some (in general quite complicated) braid that somehow depends on the original knot. Hmmmm, I wonder if there's a explanation of the colored Jones poly in terms of some skein theory diagrams. Thanks man, you've been a lot of help!!!